# regular expression for C if statementch

Tags: regex, perl

What is the regular expression for `c if statement`
Following is what I am trying but does not match

`if ( $line !~ /^if \(.\) \{/) {`

I expect it to match with `if ( a ==b ) {`

Comment: You may wish to think about what it is that you want the single wildcard `.` to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to exchange . for .* , it will acept more than 1 character inside "()"

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($line =~ /^if\s*\([^\)]+\)\s*\{/)
```

Comment: That won't work if there are compound expressions which use parens inside of the if.

Comment: I don't think you need the backslash in your character group. `[^)]`